# Question to Python Devs: Do you freeze all your package versions in your setup.py?

Tags: python, devops, dependency-management, setuptools, setup.py

I am in charge of our internal software at a data-themed startup. We build all our software in python. There has been an ongoing debate between myself and another member of my team: do we freeze our dependency requirements in our setup.py file to a specific set of versions?

To give you an idea of our current setup:

- Our main software comes to a single python library with around 30k
  lines of code.
- The library is only used internally to produce data that we then sell.
- I use a setup.py file to control the package dependencies.
- We have decent unit testing and an automated CI loop, around 70% coverage.
- We are only three developers on the team at the moment.

Until now, in the setup.py file, I thought it was best practice to not specify which version of the package I need in general, I tried to leave it as permissive as possible. To give a somewhat prolific example, I'll link airflow's setup.py which seems to do the same (albeit there are a lot of >= 's around):
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/setup.py

I only specified a version on a given dependency if and when we found a bug due to said dependency updating and breaking our code. We have continuous integration testing which usually (but not always) catches these errors. When it does catch a breakage, I have to figure out who the culprit is, and usually just fix the version to the latest one that worked. Best practice? Certainly not. But its what we have the capacity for.

I am now thinking to run pip freeze on a set of dependent package versions that works and use the output and fix the versions explicitly to a set that works, updates to dependencies be damned! This is motivated by a few thoughts:

- Our team is small, too small to be chasing down bugs from pandas updating when the old version worked fine.
- We don't publish software or even sell software, we release data. All our software is strictly for internal use, so we have a high degree of control over our environment and use cases.
- We can bump the packages whenever we want, perhaps monthly, but this will be done at a preallocated time, not just whenever a bug crops up.

My question: has anyone been in a similar position of controlling the environment for internally used software before? If so, how did you manage your dependency version? Those who haven't but are experienced DevOps/SWEs, what would you do?

Comment: You could also consider creating a custom pypi server where you only include packages that work with your software, that way you don't need to specify a version because all the versions in your server are verified to work. [This](https://hackernoon.com/custom-python-pypi-repository-409f14975374) is a pretty good tutorial

Comment: https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: Use `poetry` to pin the dependency set if you don't release a library anyway. `s/setup.py/pyproject.toml`, `s/pip install/poetry install`.